# Passing data from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, bundle

I have two activities says Activity A and Activity B.

Activity A contains Fragments AF1,AF2.
Activity B contains Fragments BF1,BF2.

Currently I am in AF1.

1. How can we pass data(bundle) from AF1 to AF2?
2. How can we pass data (bundle) from AF1 to BF2?

Comment: use `Interface` to communicate one fragment to another within in an Activity & use asynchronous message binding(intent.putExtra(bundle)) for fragment to another activity's fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to use interfaces. Here is a breakdown of the steps:

- Create an interface in your AF1 fragment - a method in that interface will be called and the data passed back through the arguments passed to it. In your activity, you implement that interface and override the method. Once the method is called, you could create another method in AF2 which you can easily call and pass the corresponding values.

The above described process has been shown in this tutorial: [how to communicate between fragments and activities](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

**FragmentOne.java**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    private Activity activity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity act){
       super.onAttach(act);
       activity = act; 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(..........){
        /* somethind was clicked here*/
        try{
           ((OnSomethingClickedListener) activity).updateActivity(position);
        }catch(ClassCastException e){}

      return view;
    }

    public interface OnSomethingCllickedListener{
       void updateActivity(int position);
    }
}
```

In your activity, implement the interface and override the method above:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity implements FragmentOne.OnSomethingCllickedListener{

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
   /* as usual here */
  }

  @Override
  public void updateActivity(int position){
     /* call FragmentTwo's method here to update the view based on the position of item clicked here*/
     FragmentTwo.updateView(position);
  }
}
```

Secondly, to decouple your activities from your fragments, use EventBus library. This is quite simple and goes like this:

- Download the jar file and add it to your project.
- Create an Event class
- Register for Events in your activities (unregister inside onDestroy)
- When you want to notify the activity of the events, just call EventBus' post method and pass back the respective data.
- Inside your activity, you need a method **onEvent(YourEventClassName event)** then you can pass the values respectively to your fragments as needed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fragments can also listen to onEvent themselves, passing directly between the fragments

Comment: Yeah that is true; so your activities do not have to know anything about your fragments in this case - highly recommended

Answer (score -1):

## Code to pass and retrieve data:

```
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();

bundle.putString("message", message);

Frag1 _fragment = new Frag1();

fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, _fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();

Bundle bundle=getArguments(); //get data

if(bundle!=null)
{
   message=bundle.getString("message")  ;
}
```